# Google shows Redirect issues in google console for the internal 301 redirects

Tags: seo, google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, technical-seo, next.js

I built my website using next Js and deployed it in Vercel. Here, I had to move some old page URLs to new ones. So, I did this,

```
301 redirect
www.example.com/book/harry-potter => www.example.com/harry-potter
```

- `www.example.com/harry-patter` was already indexed before the redirection.
  But after a few days, these URL shows as `pages with redirect` and validation failed in google console as in the following attached screenshot.
- Also, all new URLs are indexed but some of my new URLs are also in `pages with redirect` section with the extra slash at the end `example.com/book/harry-potter/`

[image]

1. Am I getting this error because of a technical error of redirection that I have done on the Next Js website?
2. Don't I get SEO benefits with this redirection issue?
3. Are there a probability of getting a google penalty for these issues?
4. Why are new URLs also in the redirection with an extra slash at the end?

Answer (score 3):

Here are the answers:

1. Am I getting this error because of a technical error of redirection that I have done on the Next Js website?
   **Ans**: No, it is not an error. It is just a notice for you, as also explained in https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7440203#page_with_redirect that

> **Page with redirect**
> = The URL redirects to another URL and therefore was
> not indexed. The final target URL might be indexed and should appear
> in this report. If you test this URL in the URL Inspection report, the
> indexed test will show the redirect; the live test will follow and
> test the redirected page, though it won't show the URL of the
> redirected and tested page.

2. Don't I get SEO benefits with this redirection issue?
   **Ans**: You get the SEO benefits as usual as explained above.
3. Are there a probability of getting a google penalty for these issues?
   **Ans**: No. You will not be penalized for doing the internal redirect. Except for the rare case that you accidentally, create a redirection loop, a NOFOLLOW tag, for instance.
4. Why are new URLs also in the redirection with an extra slash at the end?
   **Ans**: This is totally based on your default setting of the site's permalink (ie: via htaccess, or an SEO plugin), or even a specific URL's permalink that you specifically want the target URL with a non-trailing slash version to be redirected to trailing slash version.

**Bonus: Perhaps you will ask further if you need to do anything.**
**Ans**: For SEO best practice, you may reduce the redirection by changing all of the OLD version link ([www.example.com/book/harry-potter](http://www.example.com/book/harry-potter)) to your new version link ([www.example.com/harry-patter](http://www.example.com/harry-patter)) completely, which will clean up your Google Search Console report,  but it will consume a large amount of time and it usually creates a just **VERY TINY** difference. Therefore I normally just ignore this notice and work on other tasks which create much more impact for SEO.